# Application for tagging video files on a specific moment

Tags: windows-7, video

I look for a software in Windows 7 that does allow you to put tags (or notes, whatever you want to call it) on video files on specific moments. Then i would like to somehow search through those tags to find which video and at what second did i put the tag so i can easily find this second.

The reason i search for that kind of software is that i happen to watch a lot of video tutorials and i'd like to tag videos for specific tiny details of how something can be done. You know humans tend to forget details easily and i am one of them :-).

Comment: Also would be extremely useful for course recordings (e.g. MOOC videos)!